# Visio 2016, SP Designer 2013, and VWI files

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visio

I understand from reading here that I can create a workflow in `Visio`, and import it into SharePoint Designer.

I'm using SP Designer 2013 and Visio 2016.  It appears that Visio will not export a VWI, and SPD won't import anything other than a VWI.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I found that having visio 2013 installed on the same machine as SPD was required to import the diagram saved by visio 2016.  Also need to install 2013 workflows.  I am using sharepoint 2013

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Do you happen to know, if I purchase Visio 2016 through the Office365 plan, is Visio 2013 also available?

Answer (score 2):

Sharepoint Designer 2013 is not compatible with Visio 2016.
To export to Visio, you need to use the version of Visio Professional that matches the version of SharePoint Designer that you're using.
So in your case, you should have Visio 2013 to can export a Workflow designed in SharePoint Designer 2013 and vice versa.

Comment: does this answers your question?